# Can't delete files from internal storage folder

Tags: android, android-file

I want to delete all files from Download folder

[image]

I am trying this approach -

```
File mydir = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("Download")));
File lister = mydir.getAbsoluteFile();

System.out.println("Total files: " + lister.list().length);

for (String list : lister.list()) {
    File f = new File(lister, list);
    if (f.delete())
        System.out.println(list + " is Deleted!");
    else
        System.out.println(list + " not deleted!");
}
```

It doesn't work, f.delete is returning false.

I have already looked at many such questions on SO, most of them suggest the use of delete() or getCanonicalFile().delete(). This is just not working.

manifest-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: have you given the permissions at run time if you're using M or greater versions of  Android?

Comment: Yes. The code gets excuted after permisson is granted.

Comment: `System.out.println(list+" is Deleted!");` Please give an example of what is logged and you will see.

Comment: @blackapps f.delete() returns false.

Comment: I asked you to tell us the complete string that is logged. You may also tell the other one of course.

Comment: @blackapps 
I/System.out: Total files: 2
I/System.out: pg308-images.mobi not deleted!
I/System.out: LIBMG.pdf not deleted!

Comment: `System.out.println(list+" not deleted!!");`. Change to `System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath() +" not deleted!");` and then tell us the values again.

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/Download/pg308-images.epub not deleted!   .... /storage/emulated/0/Download/LIBMG.pdf not deleted!

Comment: On device or emulator? Which Android version on device or emulator?

Comment: Not emulator. It's Android device(Version 9). So API 28.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it.

My app was requesting the user for READ permission only, not WRITE.

Deleting any file requires WRITE permission. So i changed READ to WRITE, it worked!

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this
            , Manifest.permission.**WRITE**_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
     {   
       // ...
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, this will delete all files under `filePath` directory

```
File file = new File(filePath);

if (file.isDirectory()) {
    String[] children = file.list();
    if (children != null) {
        for (String aChildren : children) {
            boolean isDelete = new File(file, aChildren).delete();
            if (isDelete)
                  System.out.println(aChildren + " is Deleted!");
            else
                  System.out.println(aChildren + " not deleted!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: isDelete is false

Comment: please print log before delete add this line `Log.e("TAG", "path = " + file + " - " + aChildren);` and show me output

Comment: E/TAG: path = /storage/emulated/0/Download - pg308-images.epub    ...... E/TAG: path = /storage/emulated/0/Download - LIBMG.pdf

Comment: ohk, change this line and replace `boolean isDelete = new File(file+"/", aChildren).delete();`

Comment: output remains same

Comment: I put this code inside -                 if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this
                , Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {       .....code here .... }

Comment: Hope that doesn't cause any issue?

Comment: code inside this will execute if you grant the permission, also grant permission to `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: Permission is granted. Still don't know why it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your hint! I changed READ_ to WRITE_ . It worked! :)

Comment: `you can upvote the answer.` Why? please dont ask for points yourself. It makes a bad impression ;-).

Comment: @blackapps, thanks for your suggestion. but this is not for points, this is because this  answer solve his question and others can find a solution from this

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but more robust code:

```
                            File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("Download");

                            if ( !dir.canWrite() )
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Can not write in directory\n\n"  + dir.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                return;
                            }

                            File files [] = dir.listFiles();

                            if ( files==null )
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Could not listFiles() for\n\n"  + dir.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                return;
                            }

                            for ( File file : files)
                            {
                                if ( file.isDirectory())
                                    continue;

                                if ( ! file.delete())
                                {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Could not delete\n\n" + file.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                break;
                                }

                            }
```

Please try.